# How to have ruby Prawn column_boxes side by side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

**My Prob :** I need to have two tables side by side in pdf using ruby prawn gem.

**What did I do so far :**

```
  column_box([0, cursor], :columns => 2, :width => bounds.width) do
    table(tdy_order_stats, :header=> true) do
       row(0).style font_style: :bold # header style
    end

    table(tdy_order_types, :header=> true) do
       row(0).style font_style: :bold # header style
    end

  end
```

**Notes** : in above code **"tdy_order_stats"** and **"tdy_order_types"** are two ruby arrays. if I have lot of array elements (more than 30) it goes to the other column but second table starts after first one completes.

**Issue** : In my arrays I have only 3-4 elements. How to make them side by side in pdf????

```
          table 1                              table 2
   --------------------                  --------------------
   --------------------                  --------------------
   --------------------                  --------------------
   --------------------                  --------------------
```